# How to Instantiate an object in particular location if it has Position animation?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am instantiating an object with following code

```
public Object ball;

Instantiate(ball, hit.point , Quaternion.identity) ;
```

Where `hit.point` is a position and `ball` is a prefab I created, but unfortunately this prefab has a `Position` animation - jumping ball - and because of that as it animates it stays in animation's position. I can't even `Translate` it.

How can I move it or change animation somehow ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to solve this problem, depending on your other goals/constraints if any.

One simple approach is to separate this problem into two spaces, via the introduction of an empty parent node.

If you construct..

```
[Empty Parent Node]  (created dynamically)
 |- [Ball]           (created from your prefab)
```

..then you can still apply the animation to [Ball], now within a "local space" defined by [Empty Parent Node]. Further, you can now specify an arbitrary position for the parent node, which acts to place the ball overall.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to change your animation from a `position` animation to a `localPosition` animation. Then, you'll be able to change its `Transform.position` attribute with scripts.